# copy and paste error causing workbook to crash

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with copy and pasting from one spreadsheet to another.

I am using the following code:

```
Sub LoadnH()
Dim NF As Workbook
Dim shtMain As Worksheet

Set shtMain = Worksheets("Main")
Dim filePath As String
Dim strFileName As Variant
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*), *.*", , "Select File to Import", , False)
    shtMain.Range("filePath").Value = strFileName
    If strFileName <> False Then
        Set NF = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        NF.Sheets("Summary").Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        NF.Close False

Dim nH As Worksheet
Set nH = Worksheets("Hedge Data")
 nH.Activate
     With nH
        .Cells.Clear
        .Pictures.Delete
        .Range("A1").Select
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     End With
End If
End Sub
```

The code errors out at the following point

```
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The code show a runtime error '1004':
Method 'PasteSpecial' of object'_Worksheet' failed

how can I fix this so this error? Many times when it hits this error excel will crash and shutdown as well.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, have a read of [how to avoid using select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) which can help fix your issue by doing just that.

Comment: I've tried to stop using select as much as I could but I can't think of a way around not selecting ```.Range("A1").Select```

Answer (score 1):

To [Avoid Select and other similar methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) you can assign your value of the destination range with the value from your source range.

1. You are using the [Worksheet.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) which copies an entire `Worksheet` not the data in a `Range` of the worksheet. This will be creating a new copy of your source worksheet each time you run the code but not copying the data of the worksheet to the clipboard. (**NB:** below demonstrates using the *Before* parameter which dictates where the `Worksheet` will be copied to).
2. The [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) will copy the defined range's data to the clipboard (unless you specify the destination parameter).
3. Rather than using Copy/Paste etc. you can assign the value of the destination range with the value from your source range.

***These examples below are all for demonstration of the above points and are tested using 2 new workbooks with default names for the workbooks and worksheets.***

---

### E.g 1

```
Sub WorksheetCopyMethod()
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationwWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceWorksheet = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestinationWorksheet = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    SourceWorksheet.Copy DestinationWorksheet
End Sub
```

The result of this test creates a copy of `Sheet1` from `Book1` before `Sheet1` on `Book2`.

[image: Demonstration of example 1]

---

### E.g 2

```
Sub RangeCopyMethod()
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationwWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceWorksheet = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestinationWorksheet = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    SourceWorksheet.Range("A1").Copy
    DestinationWorksheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

This example copies cell `A1` from `Book1 - Sheet1` and pastes it to cell `A1` in `Book2 - Sheet1`.

[image: Demonstration of eg 2]

---

### E.g 3

```
Sub AvoidSelectMethod()
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationwWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceWorksheet = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestinationWorksheet = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    DestinationWorksheet.Range("A1").Value = SourceWorksheet.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

This example assigns the `Value` property of `A1` from `Book1 - Sheet1` to cell `A1` in `Book2 - Sheet1`. It's the same outcome as **E.g 2** but avoids using `Select`, `Copy` & `Paste` etc. This method is much faster and generally less error prone than the 2nd example.

[image: Demonstration of eg 3]

**Depending on your environment**, the first example may be the easiest and quickest method.